# Integração Ruby Bematech (ou similares)

Tags: ruby, impressão

Alguém já fez alguma integração Ruby com uma impressora Bematech ou outra do tipo ? Quais gems ou meios de conseguir imprimir numa impressora fiscal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe uma gem específica para impressoras Bematech, *infelizmente*.

Sabes que no caso do Windows as impressoras instalam drivers e com eles vêm uma implementação de interface provida pelo sistema operacional, certo? Se não, pois eu explico: os drivers de dispositivos externos nada mais são que implementações de interface de como fazer as coisas.

No caso da impressora, você deve acessar a **.dll** (se for Windows) através do Ruby - *usando require* - e utilizar do método de impressão da mesma.

Pra te ajudar, você pode baixar os drivers/as dlls [neste link](http://www.bematech.com.br/suporte/dwn_fisc_windows.asp).

Uma documentação mais completa e específica você encontra no endereço acima.

Answer (score 1):

No site da [Bematech](http://partners.bematech.com.br/) es existe toda a documentação das DLL's e como fazer as chamadas de suas funções, inclusive com exemplos.

Outra alternativa é utilizar o [ACBrMonitor](http://www.projetoacbr.com.br/).

Comment: Valeu pelo link do forum, não conhecia. Marquei a do @guilherme pois falou da integração direto.